# Seeker For Media Player

Tags: android, audio, media-player, android-asynctask, seek

I would assume that someone would have found an easy solution to this but I haven't found a straight-forward method. I want to build a seeker bar for playing back audio through the MediaPlayer. I haven't been able to find something like an onSeekChanged listener in the MediaPlayer object so I've built an AsyncTask that just keeps refreshing through a `while(playing)` loop and updates the duration and bar. This doesn't seem to be the best way, however, since this `while` loop causes the app to run very slowly (the audio doesn't lag, but buttons like pause are delayed). So I want to know what the best implementation is for building a seeker that is efficient. This isn't a difficult question since so many apps use it, I just want to know what the proper way of doing this should be. Thanks!

Comment: try **MediaController**, you can refer **ApiDemos for samples**. it does all the job. just **ignore the video part**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need put sleep at least 1 millisecond in your cycle whit:

```
Thread.sleep(1);
```

Second you can calculate needed time for next recheck:

```
Thread.sleep(1000 - currentPos % 1000);
```

This algorithm is used in standard MediaController.